# How to enable submit button When I entered data in all input tags in the form

Tags: reactjs

I am working with react project, with Ant designing framework. In my project I have form with four Input tags, here I disabled submit button. Now how enable submit button when I entered Information in all Input tags. Now can you please tell me how to enable submit button When I entered all the information in all Input tags.

This is my code App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Button, Card, Form, Input, Select } from "antd";

const Guestdetails = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        setData(newData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
    }


    const prefixSelector = (
        <Form.Item name="prefix" noStyle>
          <Select
            style={{
              width: 30,
              height: 10,
            }}
          >
            <Option value="86">+86</Option>
            <Option value="87">+87</Option>
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
      );
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="customizedCards">
          <Card className="cardStyle">
            <div className="main-form">
              <h5 className="idDetails">GUEST DETAILS</h5>
              <Form style={{marginLeft: "-10px"}}>
              <Form.Item
            name="name"
            noStyle
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'firstname is required' }]}
          >
            <Input type="text" name='firstname' onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 400 }} placeholder="Firstname" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            noStyle
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'lastname is required' }]}
          >
            <Input type="text" name='lastname' onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 400 }} placeholder="Lastname" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            noStyle
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'email is required' }]}
          >
            <Input type="email" name='email' onChange={handleChange} style={{ width: 400 }} placeholder="Email" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
        name="phone"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your phone number!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input type="number" name='phonenumber' onChange={handleChange} addonBefore={prefixSelector} style={{ width: 400 }} placeholder="Phone Number"  />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button className="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled type="primary">Submit</Button>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Guestdetails
```

Comment: Have tried taking a look at Formik? Formik seems to be handling what you are trying to achieve. https://formik.org/docs/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a useEffect where it watches the data changes and from there you check if all fields are already filled in.

```
const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== null) {
      setIsValid(Object.values(data).every((value) => value !== ""));
    }
  }, [data]);
```

After that you can add it in your button.

```
<Button
  className="submit"
  onClick={handleSubmit}
  disabled={!isValid} // Add this
  type="primary"
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Here's a working codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-cpkn6?file=/src/Components/guest.js:3018-3229

Edit: update your data's initial object with properties that has empty values instead of null.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: ""
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to set a `useEffect` which updates the `isFilled` state value whenever all of the Forms have valid values, thus enabling the button. Note that I haven't tested this solution, but I think it should work.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Guestdetails = () => {
  // ...
  const [isFilled, setIsFilled] = useState(false);
  const firstFormRef = useRef(null);
  const secondFormRef = useRef(null);
  // ... and so on
  
  // validate a form by ref
  const isValid = (ref) => (ref.current.getFieldsError().some((item) => item.errors.length === 0))

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstFormRef.isValid() && secondFormRef.isValid() // and so on) {
    setIsFilled(true);
   }

  }, [isFilled, firstFromRef.current, secondFormRef.current, ...]);

  return (
    ...
     <Form.Item
            ref={firstFormRef}
            name="name"
            noStyle
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'firstname is required' }]}
          >
   {* and similarly the rest too *}
    ...
<Button className="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={!isFilled} type="primary">Submit</Button>
    ...);
}
```

Comment: Hi When I use your code in my code it is saying like this Parsing error: Const declarations require an initialization value

Comment: It was probably the `isValid` function, I fixed it.